# Tkinter: pack()ing frames that use grid()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a UI for a data-display applet. I started with a tutorial and have since expanded it well beyond the scope of the tutorial, but some legacy bits remain from the tutorial that are now causing me difficulty. In particular relating to `pack()` and `grid()`.

Following the tutorial I have defined a `class Window(Frame)` object, which I then declare as `app = Window(root)` where `root = Tk()`. Within the `Window` object is an initializing function `def init_window(self)`, where my problems arise. Here is the relevant code in `init_window()`:

```
def init_window(self):
    self.master.title('Data Explorer') #changing the widget title
    self.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1) # allow widget to take full space of root

    # Initializing a grid to place objects on
    self.mainframe = Frame(root)
    self.mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S) )
    self.mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    self.mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    self.mainframe.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)
```

where the object `self.mainframe` contains a number of data selection dropdowns and buttons later on.

If I understand what this code is expected to do: it sets up the full window to be `pack()`ed with various frames. It then initializes a frame, `self.mainframe`, and within that frame initializes a `grid()`. Thus `pack()` and `grid()` do not collide. This setup was built by following the aforementioned tutorial.

This works correctly on my computer where I am developing the applet. However, when a collaborator compiles, they receive

```
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
```

on the line `self.mainframe.grid(...)`. I have replaced the `mainframe.pack()` command with a `mainframe.place()` command, but this has not resolved the issue (since his compile does not reach that point); I have not figured out a way to remove the `self.pack()` command without causing all other elements of my UI to vanish.

Can anyone help us understand what is going wrong? For reference, we are both using MacOS, and compiling with Python3. I can provide additional information as requested, within limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you exactly what is wrong. You can't use `grid` on a widget in the root window when you've already used `pack` to manage a widget in the root window.

You wrote:

> It then initializes a frame, self.mainframe, and within that frame initializes a grid()

No, that is not what your code is doing. It is not setting up a grid *within* the frame, it's attempting to use `grid` to add the widget to the root window.

First you have this line of code which uses `pack` on a widget in the root window:

```
self.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
```

Later, you try to use `grid` for another window in the root window:

```
self.mainframe = Frame(root)
self.mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S) )
```

The above isn't setting up a grid *within* `self.mainframe`, it's using `grid` to add the widget to the root window.

You need to use one or the other, you can't use both for different windows that are both direct children of the root window.

In other words, you're doing this:

```
self.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
self.mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S) )
```

but since both `self` and `self.mainframe` are a direct child of the root window, you can't do that. You need to either use `pack` for both:

```
self.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
self.mainframe.pack(...)
```

... or `grid` for both:

```
self.grid(...)
self.mainframe.grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S) )
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the response. I don't think I am totally clear on the distinction, however. Are you saying that I cannot subdivide my window into regions, packing the regions together, and using grid to place items within the region? Or are you saying that this is possible, but is not what my code is set up to do? (If the latter, can you suggest how to fix it?)

Comment: @Izzy _" Are you saying that I cannot subdivide my window into regions, packing the regions together, and using grid to place items within the region? "_ No, I am definitely not saying that. What I'm saying is you can't use `pack` to add one widget to root, and use `grid` to add another widget to root.

Comment: _" Or are you saying that this is possible, but is not what my code is set up to do?"_ - correct. It's possible, but that's not what your code is doing.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and I would like to accept your answer. However, I'm still not clear on how to implement a solution that satisfies my needs: namely, to have a (sub) grid in my window without enforcing a global grid layout. Most of my widgets use the `place()` method anyways, it is only this small subsection that uses `grid()`. Simply replacing the `self.place()` line with `self.grid()` (with appropriate arguments), as suggested, failed: only mainframe was visible in the resulting window.
I'm also unclear why the program works as-written for me, but fails for others.

Comment: @Izzy: you can use `grid` _inside_ of `mainframe`. Your problem was that you were using both `pack` and `grid` inside root. If you're using `place`, it is up to you to make sure that containers are big enough for their children. Unlike with `grid` and `pack`, using `place` won't resize containers to fit their children. That is why I recommend not using `place` except for a very small subset of layout problems.

Comment: Ok. I can't say I totally understand what I'm doing but that's par for the course w.r.t. me and coding. I erased all of the grid() references on `mainframe` and everything works as intended now, so that's good enough for me. Answer accepted, thank you for your help!